# Why I cannot change button event with JQuery .click() function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

Say I have a button whose id is "btn" and I add an event to the button as:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btn").click(function(){
        $("#label1").html((new Date()).getSeconds());
        $("#btn").click(function () {});
    };
})
```

where #label1 is a label tap supposed to show the current second.

I wish by click the button at the first time, current second will shown in the label1. And for following click on this button, nothing happen. But what I got is every time the button is clicked, new current second is shown in label1. What's wrong?

Comment: Could you show us your `HTML`? Also you *were* missing a `"` I don't know if that is the case in your actual code.

Comment: You need to unregister the previous event. You register two event handlers so both happen every click

Comment: @Script47 Edited. Just a typo.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) to bind event

```
$("#btn").one('click', function(){
    $("#label1").html((new Date()).getSeconds());
});
```

Note that `$("#btn").click(function () {});` does not unbind the event. It binds `click` event on that element one more time, so next time when the button is clicked two event handlers will be called one to update the `html` and other empty function that does nothing.

---

To unbind the event, `off()` can be used, but in this case `one()` is preferred.

```
$("#btn").on('click', function () {
    $("#label1").html((new Date()).getSeconds());

    $(this).off('click');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use [`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/).

> Attach a handler to an event for the elements. The handler is executed at most once per element per event type.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btn").one('click', function(){
        $("#label1").html((new Date()).getSeconds());
    });
})
```

At-present you are binding another click handler using `$("#btn").click(function () {});`

Answer (score 2):

Hello you can remove the click Listener the following way.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btn").click(function(){
        $("#label1").html((new Date()).getSeconds());
        $('#btn').off('click');
    });
})
```